# Why doesn't the maldet shortcut command work, but full path does?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

As you can see in the screenshot, the shortcut doesn't work, but the full path does. How can I fix it?

[image]

I am logged-in as a normal user then `su` to root, since direct root is disabled BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. I think you want the first of these.

### Su -

When you su to root, specify that you want root's environment by adding "-" to the command.

```
su -
```

Root's path includes /usr/local/sbin on many Linux distributions.

### Path

If you add /usr/local/sbin to your PATH environment variable, then you can use the short form of the name. You can do this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
```

The syntax depends on what shell you are using (the above should work for bash). If you want this to be a permanent change, add this command to your .bashrc or equivalent file in your home directory. *Do not change root's .bashrc*

### Alias

Alternatively, create an alias.

```
alias maldet=/usr/local/sbin/maldet
```

Comment: I was using plain `su` the whole time, `su -` worked. Thanks.